# I tried to display data that are in the database in to a table but it don't return anything

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to display data that are already in the database i passed these data in to a table like this

```
<?php
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                            var_dump($row);
                            //echo $last_id;
                                '<tr>
                                <td> ' . $row['ord_id'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['ord_total'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['ord_date'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['ord_qty'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_id'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_price'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field1'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field2'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field3'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field4'].'</td>
                                <td> '.$row['card_field5'].'</td>
                                </tr>';
                            var_dump($row);
                        }

                        ?>
```

i used var_dump($row) in several places it returns data but that data is not displaying in the table

Comment: You miss `echo` or something similar.

Comment: There's code missing here, for both the query and HTML table  tags. It's kind of irrelevant but not entirely. Seeing another question of yours, you connected with something else.

Comment: meaning of something else @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: I add the echo tag like this but it gives me an error `<td> '.echo .$row['ord_id'].'</td>` @freeek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing echo before creating the table at least in the code you posted. So it should be like this

```
$row = [
  'ord_id'     => 1,
  'ord_total'  => 1,
  'ord_date'   => 1,
  'ord_qty'    => 5,
  'card_id'    => 5,
  'card_price' => 123.0,
];

echo '<table><tr>
  <td> ' . $row['ord_id'] . '</td>
  <td> ' . $row['ord_total'] . '</td>
  <td> ' . $row['ord_date'] . '</td>
  <td> ' . $row['ord_qty'] . '</td>
  <td> ' . $row['card_id'] . '</td>
  <td> ' . $row['card_price'] . '</td>
</tr></table>'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` automatically echoes to the output, but strings you create don't.  You're creating a string, but never emitting it to the output.  The command you're looking for is `echo`.

For example, this just creates a string but does nothing with it:

```
'<tr><td>' . $row['ord_id'] . '</td></tr>';
```

This "echoes" that string to the output:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $row['ord_id'] . '</td></tr>';
```